# SPFile Update fails, Exists returns true

Tags: development, url, spfile, unsafe-updates

I have a block of code wrapped in an `if`:

```
mySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates();
SPFile mySPFile = web.GetFile(someURL);

if (mySPFile.Exists) /*returns true, enters code block*/ {
    //... make some updates
    mySPFile.Update(); //FAILS here, HRESULT 0x80070003 - File not found
}
```

If the file existed in the condition for the `if`, why can't it be found when I try to save the changes I made to its properties?

Comment: We have a workaround: instead of going to the file (which is within a subsite) directly by URL, we are opening the containing subsite first and then accessing it by GUID.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomand you read this article from Waldek concerning problems revolving with web.GetFile() available at http://blog.mastykarz.nl/inconvenient-spwebgetfilestring/ and confront with your code, particularly when you passing a certain URL to the method.